# Empty project symfony + mongo: Attempted to load interface CommandSubscriber in index page

Tags: mongodb, symfony4, php-7.2

I have a problem with the Symfony 4 project from MongoDB

Empty project Symfony + mongo = Attempted to load interface CommandSubscriber in index page Symfony after  installation

error:

> Attempted to load interface "CommandSubscriber" from namespace "MongoDB\Driver\Monitoring".
>   Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

```
doctrine/mongodb-odm                2.0.5  
doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle         4.1.0  
mongodb/mongodb                     1.5.2

php-mongodb                      1.6.1-1+0~20191219.12+debian10~1.gbpe14612
```

mongo 3.6.17

how to fix it?

Comment: anyone dont know?

Answer (score 0):

php-mongodb 1.6.1 is too old, use > 1.6.7 with pecl https://www.php.net/manual/fr/mongodb.installation.pecl.php